# How to get the caret position in OneNote 2016 using AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey, caret, onenote

I want to move the mouse cursor to the position of the caret. There's a built-in variable A_CaretX and A_caretY for getting the position of caret. So, I wrote something like this:

```
mousemove,% A_CaretX, A_CaretY
```

This works in Microsoft Word, but not in OneNote 2016.

Am I doing something wrong, or does it incompatible with the app? If so, is there any workaround?

I'm using Autohotkey 1.1.30.03.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth (3 years later). It took me using this AHK v2 code to realize that OneNote (Win11, Office 365) doesn't record the position of the caret.

WatchCaret() {
if CaretGetPos(&x, &y)
ToolTip "X" x " Y" y, x, y - 20
else
ToolTip "No caret"
}

Answer (score -1):

If all else fails, you can use ImageSearch to retrieve the position of a part of the caret that sticks out, in other words is far away enough from adjacent characters to be recognizable.